# BackgroundWorker behaviour on variables

Tags: c#, .net

I have below function which  works under 20 backgroundworker;

```
    bool willWork;
    void test()
    {
        if (othervalue==true)
        {
            willwork = true;
        }
        else
        {
            willwork = false;
        }
    }
```

What i want to know is, if othervalue is false on backgroundworker20, is it also true on backgroundworker20 or going to be false?

Or each backgroundworkers even they have the same variables, values on variables can be different at the same time?

Comment: Unless you declare `willWork` as `[ThreadStatic] bool willWork;` then it will be the same. Just understand that this is only because `bool` updates are atomic. If your value were a `long` or a `double` then it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Enigmativity so if i use [ThreadStatic], each threads can be different value on same variables?

Comment: For each thread, yes.

Comment: I (think I) understand your question but did you intend to mention `backgroundworker20` twice, because the question really doesn't make sense if you did.

Answer (score 0):

As written, willWork can be different for every 'instance' of your backgroundworker, changing one does not affect the others.

If you want willWork to be the same everywhere, you should mark it as a "static bool". doing so will make it a type value instead of an instance value; this means that every instance of backgroundworker will have the same willWork, and changing one will change them all

Comment: That second paragraph is irrelevant to the OP's question and thus is just confusing for them.

Comment: i could not make out whether OP wanted the value to be different or always the same; which is why i added that paragraph; for completions' sake

Comment: There is nothing in the OP's question about being the same across all instances of the class - it's just about across all instances of `BackgroundWorker`. That's why any mention of `static` variables is irrelevant.